# Float64 granularity: what is the longest possible line?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

The [IEEE](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IEEE_754-1985) defines float64's range from `-2.23e-308` to `+1.8e+308`. But what is the *granularity* implied by this range? That is, what is the maximum number of nonzero increments we can make from the minimum to the maximum? This is equivalent to drawing the flattest (nonzero slope) possible line between these points; how many samples would comprise this line, and what would be the increment size?

For example, some numeric system "alpha" has range -3 to +3, and "granularity" 1, meaning such a line is `[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]`. Neglect any memory considerations; we have a yottabyte of RAM.

Comment: Are you allowing subnormals (aka denormals)? Because that adds a lot of granularity in the "near zero" range that doesn't apply in general.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, then indeed the line's slope will be less in that region. Preferable to treat them separately, with a total increment count and size in each "region".

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The question is unclear. With IEEE-754 `binary64` format, for normal (not sub-normal) encodings, each binade comprises 2**52 discrete numbers. As a binary floating-point format which is semi-logarithmic, the increment is constant within a binade but different between binades. The question "what would be the increment size?" is therefore non-applicable.

Comment: @njuffa The answer is then "varying between binades, but constant within". The line's then piecewise-sloped, and we should be able to describe the number of points within each slope (increment size), no? The easier task should be finding the total number of points in the entire line.

Comment: Re easier task: Just multiply number of binades by number of encodings per binade, then add number of sub-normal encodings.

Comment: @njuffa Wouldn't know how to. You can post it as an answer for a +1

Comment: If you just want to know *roughly* how many samples (e.g., to within a fraction of 1%), then the answer is easy: it's 2^64, since that's close to the number of distinct binary64 floats. To get an _exact_ number you then need to modify that to take into account nans, infinities, signed zeros and subnormals in whatever way makes most sense for you. But regardless of the choices you make, the answer will still be around 2^64 (or approximately 18 million million million).

Comment: @MarkDickinson It's what I suspected, but not very clear with the diagram breakdown of a dedicated sign bit, exponent, mantissa, and all that soup; 1%'s good enough, thanks - but 0% is also interesting.